# AFNetworking 2.0 + TLS 1.2

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking-2

in my iOS App (iOS 7.0+) I use AFNetworking 2.0.

Is possibile to use TLS v.1.2?

If this is possible, how can use this?

Comment: It has been used since iOS 5.  You just need a server on the other end that runs HTTPS.  The rest will be taken care of, even without AFNetworking.  [More info here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/SecureNetworking/SecureNetworking.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of today yes you can uss TLS 1.2